# How to solve this Number Theory problem?

Tags: number-theory

If $a,b,c \in `4,5,6........21`$ and satisfy $$ {1\over a}+{1 \over b}={1 \over c} $$Where  $\gcd(b,c)=1$

Find $a,b,c = ?$

please tell me detailed solution from scratch.